# How to track the error at specific place, not where it is thrown

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, error-handling

Below is my code sample

```js
import { s3 } from 'aws-sdk'

async function usecase() {
  await myLogic1()
}

async function myLogic1() {
  //... my logic
  await s3.putObject()
}
```

when some error thrown from s3.putObject, the error stack will be like

```js
at Request.extractError (/Users/justinkao/working/AUTO-ops/mission-sticker/mission-sticker-pipeline/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/services/s3.js:711:35)
    at Request.callListeners (/Users/justinkao/working/AUTO-ops/mission-sticker/mission-sticker-pipeline/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:106:20)
    at Request.emit (/Users/justinkao/working/AUTO-ops/mission-sticker/mission-sticker-pipeline/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:78:10)
    at Request.emit (/Users/justinkao/working/AUTO-ops/mission-sticker/mission-sticker-pipeline/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:686:14)
    at Request.transition (/Users/justinkao/working/AUTO-ops/mission-sticker/mission-sticker-pipeline/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:22:10)
    at AcceptorStateMachine.runTo (/Users/justinkao/working/AUTO-ops/mission-sticker/mission-sticker-pipeline/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:14:12)
    at /Users/justinkao/working/AUTO-ops/mission-sticker/mission-sticker-pipeline/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:26:10
    at Request.<anonymous> (/Users/justinkao/working/AUTO-ops/mission-sticker/mission-sticker-pipeline/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:38:9)
    at Request.<anonymous> (/Users/justinkao/working/AUTO-ops/mission-sticker/mission-sticker-pipeline/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:688:12)
    at Request.callListeners (/Users/justinkao/working/AUTO-ops/mission-sticker/mission-sticker-pipeline/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:116:18)
    at Request.emit (/Users/justinkao/working/AUTO-ops/mission-sticker/mission-sticker-pipeline/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:78:10)
    at Request.emit (/Users/justinkao/working/AUTO-ops/mission-sticker/mission-sticker-pipeline/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:686:14)
```

The error stack only track where the aws package function calls (or some method of some class), not exactly the place where my function (`logic1()`, or `usecase()`) calls.

Is there any way to make it track to my code? or add a additional stack of where my function called?